# code: Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not installed

Tags: debian

I am trying to install a couple of programs (for example [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download)) but I always get this error:

> code: Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not installed

I also tried `apt install -f file/path` but still get the same error.

I understand that the error is saying whatever I'm running depends on `libgconf-2-4` and that doesn't currently exist, but shouldn't Debian download and install all dependencies automatically? Or at least when I use the `-f` flag?

**UPDATE**

Here's the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

[image]

Comment: I can't copy/paste the Terminal text from the Guest to the Host for some reason, so I'll put a screenshot.

Comment: Yep, [see here](https://hastebin.com/osuxeqizax.coffeescript).

Comment: I did, but got the error again, here's a [screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/k9Qv3gtZ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

either try to install it manually by `apt install libgconf-2-4` or if it is broken (the problem i had) you can try to fix it by `apt --fix-broken install` and that fixed it for me

Comment: The first one does not work. Could you explain the second one?